# Server cannot reached in different locations. Who I should blame, domain registrar or hosting company?

Tags: domain-name-system

My site is not reachable by 36 Host of 50 host all over the world: http://host-tracker.com/check_res_ajx/7999858-0/

Hosting company told me it's the problem of DNS and Domain Registrar (My DNS Server is DNS-DIY Which is free service by OnlineNic) and Domain Registrar told me this is a problem of Hosting company (iWeb).

My primary domain is www.sanaram.com and my Nameservers are ns1.risaman.com=>184.107.58.109 and ns2.risaman.com=>184.107.61.137

Can you please tell me how can I understand where is the root of evil? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is certainly a registrar-problem and has nothing to do with your personal internet-access. If a site is inaccessible on more than your own location your domain is not yet propagated to every rootserver, contact your Domain registrar and show them the above link.

edit : http://www.sanaram.com/ works from here (Germany)

Comment: Thank for your useful answer. Here is something weird. Domain RISAMAN.COM is seen from everywhere without any problem: http://host-tracker.com/check_res_ajx/8000140-0/ But domain 1EMPERATOR.COM which is pointing to NS1/NS2.RISAMAN.COM is NOT: http://host-tracker.com/check_res_ajx/8000156-0/ What does it mean? (Both domain point to same Nameserver)

Comment: same here : domain not yet propagated, either you need to wait a few more hours (up to 2 days) in order to access the site through its name or your registrar needs to fix their servers .... i had a similar problem yesterday with one of my domains - my registrar was at fault.
http://www.1emperator.com/ is indeed not accessible from my location, i do remember that the first char in a domain-name must not be a number, i think this violates certain rules hence the domain got blocked ... but im not quite sure about that, ask your registrar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the name servers listed for your domain (ns1.risaman.com and ns2.risaman.com) are not answering authoratatively for your domain (sanaram.com). Have you set up the sanaram.com zone or requested that it be set up by whomever manages the name servers at ns1.risaman.com and ns2.risaman.com?